# Ist die Jugendsprache Sprachverfall oder Sprachwandel?

Tags: teen-slang

Diese Frage bezieht sich nicht auf Ihr Wissen, sondern vielmehr auf Ihre Meinung/Beobachtung. Ich möchte gerne wissen, welche Meinung unter Muttersprachlern und unter Lernenden überwiegt und warum, denn ich habe bisher starke Argumente von den beiden Seiten gehört und möchte mir eine Meinung bilden.

Comment: Auch wenn das eine interessante Frage ist, hat sie leider nichts mit dem Deutschen an sich zu tun. Jugendsprache gibt es auch in anderen Sprachen. Und auch, ob sie als Verfall oder Wandel einer Sprache angesehen wird, ist kein Spezifikum des Deutschen.

Comment: Ok, verstehe. Ich werde dann auf gutefrage.net nachfragen :)

Comment: Ich schließe diese Frage, weil sie eine Umfrage ist und somit nicht für dieses Format geeignet. Überdies wird so eine Umfrage (ob hier oder woanders) Dir vermutlich nicht helfen, Dir eine eigene Meinung zu bilden, sondern bestenfalls sagen, was eine gewisse Gruppe von Menschen denkt (deren Meinung bestenfalls genauso qualifiziert ist wie Deine eigene). Was Du machen kannst, ist hier oder z. B. auf [linguistics.se] danach fragen, wie Jugendsprache fachlich eingestuft wird.

Comment: Insbesondere in diesem doch von einer gewissen Überzahl sprachwissenschaflich angehauchter Nutzer dominierten Diskussionsgelände würde es mich wundern, wenn sich viele Stimmen fänden, die Jugendsprache als Sprachverfall einstuften. Für Linguisten ist Sprache in stetem Wandel begriffen, und verschiedene Gruppen der Gesellschaft pflegen ihre... ja, nun eben: Soziolekte, zum Beispiel zur Abgrenzung von anderen Gruppen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Sprachwissenschaft tendiert dazu, [deskriptiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deskriptive_Linguistik) zu sein. So oder so ändert dies nichts am Umfrage-Charakter der Frage.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft   Ja, genau, das sagte ich ja auch (wenn auch umständlicher).

Comment: Es wird aber auch nach Beobachtungen gefragt und nach Argumenten. Beides lässt sich dem Reich der Objektivität insofern zuordnen, als man von der persönlichen Beobachtung auf das allgemein Beobachtbare abstrahiert. Da nicht ausgeschlossen ist, dass sich Jugendsprache in verschiedenen Sprachen unterschiedlich entwickeln kann ist auch nicht gesagt, dass es für das Deutsche keine eigene Antwort gibt. Dies ist keine rein spekulative Vermutung, da die dt. Jugendsprache viele Anglizismen aufnimmt, was die englische Jugendsprache umgekehrt sicher nicht tut. Wenn die dt. Jugendsprache gefragt ist ...

Comment: ... könnte man also die Überschrift spezifizieren und wieder öffnen, ansonsten gehört es wohl zu Linguistics. Zu rügen bleibt noch, dass die Überschrift eine falsche Dichotomie eröffnet, denn ein Verfall ist natürlich immer eine Art des Wandels. Alternativen wären Spaltung, Bereicherung, temporäre Belebung und womögliche andere Formen des Wandels.

Comment: @userunknown würden sie also eine andere Überschrift vorschlagen?

Comment: (Ich schlage vor, das "Du" zu benutzen, auch wenn wir es ablehnen, um uns an die Gepflogenheiten hier anzupassen.) Das ist Deine Frage, und Du musst wissen, was Du fragen willst. a) Jugendsprache allgemein - dann nein, dann gehört es zu Linguistics. b) Deutsche Jugendsprache im speziellen - dann ja. Ob dann außer mir jmd. für reopen votiert ist aber offen.

Comment: Mir geht es nicht ums reopen sondern vielmehr darum, ob die Frage an sich überhaupt korrekt ist. Deswegen habe ich auch gefragt, wie die Überschrift lauten soll

Comment: @YahooDE: Da Überschriften kurz sein müśsen würde das m.E. gehen, auch wenn ich schreiben würde "Ist Jugendsprache ein Ausdruck des Sprachverfalls" oder "ein Mosaikstein" oder "ein Treibstoff" - je nach dem was ich sagen will. Das "oder Sprachwandel" gehört aber weg oder ersetzt, weil, wie gesagt, ein Verfall ein Wandel ist.

Comment: Vielleicht könnte man auch fragen: "Nimmt das Publikum in Deutschland Jugendsprache als Sprachverfall wahr?"

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Welches ("unbeteiligte") Publikum denn? Die von Aphasie betroffenen?

Comment: @tofro - Du meinst nicht vielleicht eher die von Anakusis Betroffenen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sprache ist im ständigen Wandel. Einen Verfall im eigentlichen Sinn gibt es nicht bei Sprachen. Eher Stillstand, wenn eine Sprache nicht mehr gesprochen wird (wie Latein z.B.). Aber auch in der lateinischen Sprache kamen später noch Wörter hinzu.

Comment: Hier spricht der Linguist.